# CLion CMakeLists.txt library paths for different build systems

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have a project currently running on XCode.
As we enlarge our Team, we have 2 developers on Ubuntu. So we tried to switch to CLion.

The problem now is, that the include paths are totally different and the "find_package" does not work.

Is there a way to solve this problem without defining the path for each build system?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches:

1. set the flag -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= in the workspace settings. Make sure you use the .gitignore tool to prevent pushing ignore the un-necessary files in the .idea/ folder.
2. have a CMakeLists.txt to provide the environment, and have that CMakeLists.txt include your project's CMakeLists.txt.

The second way is probably more manageable as it allows you to:

a) define each compilation environment explicitly.

b) avoid polluting the project's CMakeLists.txt file with environment-specific noise.

Normally, when you build and *install* libraries, they are installed in the following directory structure:

`<base directory such as /usr/local>/bin`

`<base directory such as /usr/local>/lib`

`<base directory such as /usr/local>/include`

the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH= should specify the "`<base directory such as /usr/local>`" part. Not the "`/include`" part.

If you have not installed required libraries in their normal structure, then all bets are off and you might have to specify include and library directories explicitly.

At this point, may I guide you towards the documentation?

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package

https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: Thank you!
So if i define the -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, CMake does not find the header files.
Even if i add a include path. Is there another flag for header files?

Comment: @fredalex updated answer. Difficult to help you more without knowing more about how you build the pre-requisites.

Comment: Thank you!
I got the problem with boost and openssl.
So everything works on Ubuntu.
On Mac, they are installed with Homebrew (/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1). 

If i add these directories to the DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, i still get the error, that the header files are not found. (if i add them to the include path manually, everything works)

Comment: @fredalex homebrew... :( That's why I created the sanity build library for cmake... https://github.com/madmongo1/sanity very much a work in progress but it saves me hours...

Comment: as there is a little lack of documentation, could you give me a short hint what this is about and how i get started? Thank you very much!

Comment: i include sanity as a subproject in my cmake project, include(sanity/cmake/sanity.cmake), and then call sanity_require(LIBRARY boost VERSION latest COMPONENTS thread system) (for example).
This builds targets sanity::boost::system, sanity::boost::thread and sanity::boost that you can add to a target_link_libraries() command

Comment: thank you. i will really have to try that if nothing else works!
But even if i install all the libraries manually. I always get, that the include files are not found! boost is under "/usr/local/boost" installed correctly (works with xcode). And if i set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to /usr/local/boost, header files are not found!

Comment: further more, the biggest problem seems to be the mysqlcppconn.

Comment: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH should normally be set to /usr/local, not /usr/local/boost.